# How to get value of checkbox added in vsfolderdialog.wiz file

Tags: deployment, dialog, installation, formwizard, customizing

I have added a checkbox in vsfolderdialog.wiz file for customizing Folder Path dialog in Setup and Deplopyment Project. But i have not an idea how i will get its value on which i have to take some decisions.

Note: I am using custom installer action for accessing its value and tried to get Installer.Context.Parameters on Install event

Please help me in this regard.

Regards,
Jhan Zaib

Comment: You can use the installer property associated with your checkbox.

Answer (score 0):

[Checkbox Control](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa367854%28v=VS.85%29.aspx) in Windows Installer is associated with a property. Usually when checkbox is selected, its associated property will have the value you defined; when it's cleared, the property is set to null.